# Return from function from inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have the following function.

```
function foo() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
     await someFunctionThatWillAlwaysBeRejected().catch(err => {
       return reject(err);
     })
     console.log("Some output that should never be shown");
     resolve();
   })
  }
```

The function rejects as expected but after it continues to run until the end. I guess it's because the `return` inside the catch only returns from the anonymous function and not from the entire `Promise`. The question is if there is any way of returning from inside the `catch` so the code won't continue to execute after that? I know I can wrap everything in `try` `catch` instead of using `.catch` but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is if there is any way of returning from inside the catch

No.

> I know I can wrap everything in try catch instead of using .catch but I'm trying to avoid that.

`async`/`await` allows you to do that precisely so you can solve the problem you have. Stop avoiding it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
 someFunctionThatWillAlwaysBeRejected().then(result => {
   console.log("Some output that should never be shown");
   resolve();
 })
 .catch(err => {
   return reject(err);
 })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those promise wrapper, because async function is always return Promise. Therefore, your code could be simplified:

```
async function foo() {
     await someFunctionThatWillAlwaysBeRejected();
     console.log("Some output that should never be shown");
}
```